# Close Excel file dynamincally in Python

Tags: python, xlwings

I am downloading few excel reports from a web portal. New downloaded excel is getting open automatically after completeing the download.
I want to close web portal as soon as download is finish and I am amending the the report then close excel too (amendment is not relevant here).

I am using below code but its not working:

```
fullname = []
for workbook in xw.books:
    fullname.append(workbook.fullname)
    #need to wait untill new excel report is open
    while filepath and keyword not in fullname: #PROBLEM: fullname is not dynamic in while loop  
        sleep (1)
    else:
        driver.quit()
        .
        .
        .
        workbook.save()
        workbook.close()
```

Comment: can you explain more the problem you are having with your code ?

Comment: problem is with **while** loop. I want to wait untill new excel report is open so that I can close the webdriver and workbook. In my code i m running a **for** loop to get all the open excel path then running a while loop to identify which excel to close.

Comment: try separating the two loops with additional for loop. first for loop should do the first part, then write another follow which can iterate through the elements of `fullname`, and then you can keep the while loop inside this, just like your code

Comment: Thanks Kishore. Do you mind commenting as answer with code. I am getting confuse here.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of variables are not clear here, like whats `xw` or `keyword`,still based on understanding,

```
fullnames = []
for workbook in xw.books:
    fullnames.append(workbook.fullname)

for fullname in fullnames:
    # run os /subprocess module to achieve it
    while filepath and keyword not in fullname: #PROBLEM: fullname is not dynamic in while loop  
        sleep (1)
    else:
        driver.quit()
        .
        .
        .
        workbook.save()
        workbook.close()
```

Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: Its going into infinite loop as **while** loop's fullname doesn't have newly opened excel file path.

Comment: can you show me complete code how are you getting list of all opened excel file path? if 100+ loc, can u push it to some repo and share link? (if its not confidential kinda thing)

Comment: First **for** loop is giving me the list of all open excel files. Since new excel is getting open after this step, that's why **while** loop won't have the link of new file in fullname variable;  hence not working in a desired manner.